# How to read values from multiple nodes in xml having element in TextValue format using C#

Tags: c#

This is the sample xml we are using,Need to read the values in TextValue Attribute

```
<SelectApplicableVehicle>         
        <TextValue> 
           
            <text>2000 - 57y-ry5465-Truck</text>
            <value>2000 - 57y-ry5465-Truck-21063</value>
        </TextValue>
        <TextValue>
            <text>2008 - 57y-3546-Truck</text>
            <value>2008 - 57y-3546-Truck-21064</value>
        </TextValue>
    </SelectApplicableVehicle>
```

Comment: A bit more information would be good. What have you already tried. What is not working. What is the expected result.

Comment: In the above XML, TextValue is an element, not an attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("TextValue").Select(x => new
            {
                key = (string)x.Element("text"),
                value = (string)x.Element("value")
            }).ToList();

            
        }
    }
  
}
```